# scaffolding - Is there any alternative to angular-cli for service generation?

Tags: soa, scaffolding

I'm looking for a generic `scaffolding tool` (JS or Python code output) like `yeoman`, that supports `service generation` feature like in angular-cli (`ng g s myservice`).

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at **Telosys** : http://www.telosys.org/

This tool is designed to scaffold very quickly. It uses simple/light text model (DSL) with customizable templates (based on Velocity).
It can generate code for any kind of languages and you can create your own templates.

For **JS** with NodeJS you can try this set of templates: https://github.com/so-technology-watch/telosys-templates-nodejs

For **Python** you can use the following templates :

- Python REST with Bottle : https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/python-web-rest-bottle
- Python persistence with SQL alchemy : https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/python-persistence-sqlalchemy

You can also generate PostMan scripts for REST tests with: https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/web-rest-postman